# GWT client-side HTML5 database storage (Web SQL Database)

Tags: database, gwt, html, gwt2

I wonder if there is an API for using [Database Storage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase/) in GWT 2.x or I should use native code like this instead?

```
var database = openDatabase("Database Name", "Database Version"); 
database.executeSql("SELECT * FROM test", function(result1) { 
    // do something with the results 
    database.executeSql("DROP TABLE test", function(result2) { 
        // do some more stuff 
        alert("My second database query finished executing!"); 
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [gwt-mobile-webkit](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-mobile-webkit/) project provides these bindings so you don't have to write them yourself. Don't let the name fool you, it'll work on a desktop browser too.

Answer (score 4):

gwt-mobile-webkit as of now, will not run on the latest desktop browsers, since it uses the WebSQL API that is no longer supported by the latest browsers like Firefox 4+.

I have written a small library for doing client side storage. It can work with all browsers that support localstorage-api (practically all HTML5 browsers including the smart phone browsers) and allows you to store data in object stores and databases.

You can check it out here:
https://code.google.com/p/gwt-localstorage-db/